# Subtraction in list of lists using modulo

Tags: python

Given a list of lists , how is it possible to get the sum of the subtraction(in modulo)of an element from adjacent lists(and certificate that the lists are adjacent)?

Example:
`l = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,5],[4,40]]` 
`the sum should be sum = |10-20|+|5-40|`

Comment: Well, what have *you* tried on your own before asking for help?

Comment: `newlist = [abs(l[i][1]-l[i+1][1]) for i in range(0, len(l), 2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, this can help you:

```
sum(map(lambda x,y: abs(x[1]-y[1]), l[1::2], l[::2]))
```

this will separate both alternate part of list into two lists and subtract each of them separately using lambda, we are taking second element of each of newly formed list of lists for subtraction, taking their absolute value (|-a|=a) and the adding them all using our sum function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
l = [[1,10],[2,20],[1,5],[2,40]]
result = 0
for ii in range(int(len(l)/2)):
    result += abs(l[ii*2][1]-l[ii*2+1][1])
print(result)
```